# Django render in html Aggregation

Tags: django, filter, render, aggregation, templatetags

I'm trying to output a conditional sum / aggregation via django in html. Though not sure what to put in my template?

see below :

in views.py: (part of my code )

```
total_paid = CF.objects.filter(type='Payment').aggregate(Sum('amount')
return render(request, 'budget/budget_detail.html', {'paid': total_paid })
```

in budget/budget.html :

```
{{ paid }}
```

output is as follows in my browser : {'amount__sum': Decimal('-1500')}

can anyone help me? thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
 {{ paid.amount__sum }}
```

Although you may just want to provide a key for the sum in your aggregation to make it a nicer variable name

```
...aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
{{ paid.total }}
```